# JQuery Validation not posting data to backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have something weird going on that I am trying to work out. I have a simple submitHandle that passes one bit of data to my PHP file

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form-process.php",
        data: {
            'customer':  $("input[name='customer']:checked").val()
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(textStatus)
    });
    return false;
}
```

If I output `$("input[name='customer']:checked").val()` I get the expected value of yes or no.  Now in my PHP file, I am simply doing

```
echo json_encode($_POST["customer"]);
```

This seems to produce the error

> Undefined index: customer

If I just check `$_POST` it returns an empty array.

Am I missing something here? Is there a reason this data isn't making it to the backend?

Comment: Check the network tab in the devtools to see if the post data is being sent with the request or not.

Comment: can you tell us wich version Jquery used??

Comment: Sure, jQuery v2.1.4 and jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.17.0

Comment: so this ajax request is to old regarding your syntax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ 1.4 <= 1.5.x

Comment: Really?  I can't see any new version of it?

Comment: @kate_hudson i add a answer try if is good for you.

Comment: If I were you, before checking the value of the `$_POST` array in your PHP file, I would test the value of `$("input[name='customer']:checked").val()` in the JavaScript developer console of your web browser. I.e. `console.log($("input[name='customer']:checked").val())` . Make sure you're getting the right value back in JS before you send it to your PHP file. Your Ajax post syntax looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$("input[name='customer']:checked") ? true : false`  because if the input is not checked `$("input[name='customer']:checked")` will return `null` and then you will have `null.val()` which is not correct

```
data: {
        customer:  $("input[name='customer']:checked") ? true : false
    }
```

Comment: How about, `var customerVal = $("input[name='customer']:checked") ? true : false;` Then: `data: {'customer':  customerVal}`. I think a bool is better here.

Comment: I considered yes and no based on the question ... but yes boolean will be absolutely better, updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this method :

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "form-process.php",
  data: { customer: $("input[name='customer']:checked").val() }
}).done(function(response) {
console.log( "Data Saved: " + response);
}).error(function(error){
   console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: I actually just found out what the problem was.  I was running this locally with XAMPP at something must be wrong here.  As soon as I put it online, I got the data.  Not sure why running it locally is causing this problem though, will need to look into it

Comment: Locally depends of you internal network proxy vpn or firewall routers can cos problem if you call some external links. But no sure you need to analyzed your logs php, apaches to find why.